# TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, discord.py

This is part of my script that handels getting a custom prefix (If needed I can send all of it)

```py
settings = json.load(open("settings.json"))


# funtion that gets the prefix from the settings file depening on guild id
def get_prefix(bot, messages):
    guild = messages.guild.id
    guild = str(guild)
    settings["guilds"][0][guild][0]["prefix"] = prefix
    return prefix


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, help_command=None)


@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print(f"Joined {guild.name}")
    print(f"{guild.name} has {guild.member_count} members")
    print(f"{guild.name}'s id is {guild.id}")
    print(f"{guild.name}'s owner is {guild.owner}")
    print(f"{guild.name}'s region is {guild.region}")

    settings["guilds"][0][guild.id][0]["prefix"] = "?"
    settings["guilds"][0][guild.id][0]["guild_name"] = guild.name
    settings["guilds"][0][guild.id][0]["guild_id"] = guild.id
    settings["guilds"][0][guild.id][0]["guild_owner"] = guild.owner
    settings["guilds"][0][guild.id][0]["guild_region"] = guild.region

    json.dump(settings, open("settings.json", "w"))


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("------")
    print("Logged in as")
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print("------")


@client.command()
async def prefix(ctx, *, prefix):
    guild = ctx.guild.id
    settings["guilds"][0][guild][0]["prefix"] = prefix

    json.dump(settings, open("settings.json", "w"))
```

That's my current script for getting the prefix and setting it depending which server it called from.

It worked great on my test bot, but when I transferred it over it seemed not to anymore.

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 975, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 886, in get_context
    prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 831, in get_prefix
    ret = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(prefix, self, message)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 341, in maybe_coroutine
    value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\furrc\Code\Python\GIF Bot\bot.py", line 16, in get_prefix
    settings["guilds"][0][guild][0]["prefix"] = prefix
TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable
```

Thats my error code I get, it says `TypeError: 'Command' object is not subscriptable` but I have no idea where Command is, its not included in my .json file

```json
{
    "guilds": [
        {
            "771773406144233514":[
                {
                    "id": 771773406144233514,
                    "name": "Makashi's Bot Testing Server", 
                    "prefix": "!"
                }
            ]
            ,
            "810686563138142218":[
                {
                    "id": 810686563138142218,
                    "name": "SPAM",
                    "prefix": "?"
                }
            ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

That's my json folder and it doesnt contain Command in it, so I'm not sure why it being called.

Comment: Debug it, do `print(type(settings["guilds"]))`, then `print(type(settings["guilds"][0]))`, ... until you find the problem

Comment: And while you're at it, check what `get_prefix` returns. It's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, `settings` variable was shadowed with some other `settings` from some library you use. Try to make it `guilds_settings` and refer to the variable by using the `global` keyword.